# Issue with re-adding a relationship in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm in a bit of a jam. I have this table with a few of relationships, one of which was referencing itself (let's call this relationship **A**).

I needed to delete some rows from this table but because one of my relationships was referencing itself I was unable to do so. Therefore, I simply deleted relationship **A** and saved the table.

After deleting the rows that I wanted to delete, I attempted to re-add relationship **A**, however I am now presented with the following error message.

> 'T_FormulaireQuestion' table
>   Unable to create relationship 'FK_T_FormulaireQuestion_T_FormulaireQuestion'.
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_T_FormulaireQuestion_T_FormulaireQuestion". The conflict occurred in database "VilleG", table "dbo.T_FormulaireQuestion", column 'intFormulaireQuestionID'.

I believe what this message is saying is that my relationship **B** is causing a conflict when trying to re-add relationship **A**.

My question is, how can I re-add relationship **A**? Do I have to delete relationship **B**, re-add relationship **A** and finally re-add relationship **B**?

I'd prefer not have to delete the entire table as I have important data within it.

Please use the following image as a reference.

[image]
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: _"I believe what this message is saying is that my relationship B is causing a conflict "_ How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Could you provide the scripts for the relationships? The images are not readable.

Comment: Regarding your initial issue of not being able to delete tows: Have you tried executing a single DELETE that removes all of the related rows at once? The table would be consistent before and after the operation. The question is would a foreign key constraint violation occur in between? Playing with a small example it seems to work, even when two rows reference each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could not delete rows because that would have violated the relationship. After forcing the delete to run, the relationship is, of course, violated... You have destroyed data integrity. Your delete operation was invalid. You silenced the error message but you still executed the error.

Fix the data before adding the constraint back. Probably, this means deleting any rows that are dependent on the now deleted rows in `T_FormulaireQuestion`. You have to figure out which rows have no matching row in `T_FormulaireQuestion` and delete them.

You can add the constraint back once it is no longer violated. Note that any violation of the constraint implies that your data is invalid. You should fix this state.

Comment: Since relationship A is referencing itself, I ran a select statement on the primary key intFormulaireQuestionID for the rows that I deleted, however 0 results were returned. How do I find the rows that are dependent on the rows that I deleted?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM T AS t1 WHERE blueprintid IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T AS t2 WHERE t1.blueprintid = t2.id)`. The fact that this is a same-table FK does not matter for the query.

Comment: Excellent! Worked like a charm, your help has been greatly appreciated :)